# In compton scattering, is the emitted photon the same as the incident one?

Tags: scattering

In Compton  scattering (you can extend to Raylegh and Rutherford light scattering if you wish to), is the emitted photon the same as the incident one?
In other words, should we consider one photon as being absorbed and one emitted or should we consider that a single photon loses energy?

Comment: here's the background of the question before the mods mob closes it for not being worded in a way that pleases them : in 2 instances I've been told that scattering of photons doesnt necessarily involves energy exchanges, whereas I believe that even if the NET energy exchange may be 0, it's necessary for the photon to give it's energy to the atom (and therefore the photon must be destroyed) in a way permitted by energy levels of a kind or another before the atom re-emits a new photon.

Comment: see also https://www.quora.com/How-is-Compton-scattering-possible-if-a-photons-energy-must-either-be-fully-absorbed-by-the-electron-or-fully-re-emitted-according-to-the-photoelectric-effect

Comment: Instead of closing the answer if you can't answer it, it's better  to answer that the question can't be answered.

Comment: Note that most closed questions are those that can be answered, as the closure reason is something else. //  The question background fits better to the question itself, the comments are better suited for short response to the question feedback comments. And - they should not be longer than the question itself, it is sign of low question elaboration effort. ( I have not downvoted. )

Comment: when I put too much background in the question body itself I get my question closed too because for some reason people don't like when I make assumptions. I believe this question is perfectly readable as it is. And I understand discussing the "oneness" of a photon is problematic. But I chose to invite such discussion nonetheless

Comment: But be aware SE sites are Q/A sites, not discussion sites. For the latter, the physicsforums.com may fit better, or chat feature of SE. // It is perfectly readable question in the format Quora expects and accepts, but not in the format SE sites expect and usually demand. 3-line questions usually get closed at any SE site for lack of explicit a priori research effort.

Comment: Well then , 
-either my question can be answered and then it should (not a duplicate so far)
-my question can be answered but pple dont know how: then it should be left open 
-my question can't be answered then it should be answered that it can't be answered for xyz reason

Comment: Many questions should be closed and not to be answered, regardless if the answer is trivial, complicated or unknown. If you followed the site policy then your questions would not get closed.

Comment: ok then tell me what rule I did break

Comment: That is your homework, not mine. Read the question policy and get inspired by questions that have not been closed.

Comment: am I also supposed to guess why someone voted to close my question without providing any justification just by using my mindreading superpowers ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compton Scattering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52436/compton-scattering)

Comment: Hi Manu, I think it's a perfectly good question but it has been asked before. I've linked the duplicate above. For what it's worth, the question doesn't really have an answer because it depends what you mean by a photon. If we take it as a momentum state (a Fock state) then any change to the momentum makes it a different photon, but then you could apply the same criterion to electrons and we would not normally call a scattered electron a different particle.

Comment: well @JohnRennie the question has been closed not because of duplication but because apparently it's "not clear"....go figure

Answer (score 1):

In short, for *Compton* scattering, I would tend to consider that a single photon of wavelength $\lambda$ is incident on a particle which imparts some of its energy on the particle, and afterwards has wavelength $\lambda'$ and a new direction of travel. It's the same photon, just with new energy relative to the collision event that occurred, and relating to the angle of scattering.

This interpretation comes from the definition of scattering, which differs from absorption. But one could call the Compton effect a 'partial absorption', due to the fact that some energy is lost to the particle.

The energy of the incident photon determines the effect that occurs for a collision, with long wavelength light giving dominance to Rayleigh scattering (no change in $\lambda$), wavelengths in the UV range giving dominance to photoelectric effect (photon absorption, assuming the incident photon $f$ is above the cutoff), and high energy wavelengths like X-ray giving dominance to the Compton effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way whatsoever to identify individual photons, either in the same state (which are automatically considered identical), let alone in different states. All you can do is count the number of photons that are in a certain state (wavenumber vector, polarization) before an event and after the event.

Otherwise you would have to propose a procedure, that would allow to "stick a label" to a certain photon, and track the persistence of that label. But then the photon would have to have properties (the "label") beyond those that photons are agreed to have, which makes it something different than a photon.

Therefore, the question if the "emitted photon is the same as the incident one" is physically meaningless.

Comment: why no one has an issue with fluorescence having 2 distinct absorbed and emitted photons, and why is it so hard with scattering ?

Comment: During Fluorescence one photon is absorbed, and one photon is emitted afterwards. Whether they are distinct is determined by their states. If the emitted photon happens to have the same state as the absorbed, then they are identical by definition, otherwise they are different by definition. Photons are not like trees. You can scratch your initials into one of two identically looking trees, and then they are also visibly different. But you can't scratch your initials into a photon. They have no other properties  but momentum and polarization.

Comment: I'm confused: how can you say for sure that in compton scattering the photon isnt absorbed and re emitted like in the fluorescence case or as explained here ?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/52445/26275

Comment: You should clarify whether your question aims at understanding identical particles (of which photons are one species, namely of type boson, i.e. arbitrarily many can be in the same state, hence we can only count their number) or at understanding scattering vs. absorption.

Comment: excellent question: my current feeling is that scattering and absorbtion are the same except in terms of what is excited, for absorbtion, it's the electrons  around the atom, and for compton's it's whatever charged particle.
I am asking about the oneness of the photon in order to determine if there is something fundamentally different between  scattering(1 photon ???) vs. absorption (where we commonly talk about 2 photons).

Comment: The difference between scattering and absorption is that scattering inevitably results in the conversion of an ingoing photon into an outgoing ("scattered") photon of different momentum, while absorption results in the vanishing of an ingoing photon, and the re-emission is only optional. But I have the feeling you already knew that. The speculation about which photon is which is practically (and conceptually) irrelevant.

Comment: well, what about fluorescence vs scattering ? In that case they both re-emit (it's semantics, but that's what it is).

Comment: Yeah, what about fluorescence?

Comment: well you can't say fluorescence is different than scattering because in both cases a photon is emitted. Should I conclude both are the same ? (considering the only difference you noted between absorbtion and scattering was the emission of a photon)

Answer (score 0):

Compton scattering is the scattering between an incoming photon and an electron, not between a photon and an atom.  The formulae could be used for photon - atom scatterin **IFF** the photon is far from the difference in energy levels of the atom, and the atom is a negative  ion.

[image: compt]

In mainstream theory the crossection for scattering is calculated using Feynman diagrams , [the lowest order shown above.](http://redberry.cc/documentation:tutorials:compton_scattering_in_qed)

As in main stream physics electrons are elementary point particles, there is no way they can be excited to a different mass, as would have to happen if the photon were absorbed.

The two incoming particles on the left have four vectors  with their invariant mass on shell. The same is true for the two outgoing particles.  The electron between the two vertices ia a virtual electron, its mass is not onshell, it just has the quantum numbers of an electron to conserve and correctly account for them, as a mnemonic.

One says that the same electron goes out because it has distinctive quantum numbers. As the photon is only characterized by its $energy=hν$,  and zero mass , as it has a different energy it can be considered a different photon.

In a more complicated reaction, if many electrons would come out, one would have the same difficulty of attributing the title "same" to an electron. Only calculation of cross sections, i.e. many interactions summed, compared with plots of the electrons energy distributions one would be able to show the "leading" electron, not on individual  events.(This is extensively done with parton distribution functions, to determine the content of quarks in highe energy physics experiments)