Is cosmic background radiation the same photons bouncing around?
Or are "new" photons from perhaps later stages of the expansion encountered?

Please don't do that. Your question needs to make sense independently, and not be a continuation of the title. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173271/334566 & links therein

On whether a scattered photon is the same photon: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/52480/123208

The very early universe was so hot that electrons and nuclei could not combine to form atoms. These free charges bounced photons around very well. Things were very hot, so there were a lot of photons to bounce.
Then around 300,000 years after the Big Bang, things cooled to the point that atoms could form. These were H and He atoms, which are transparent. All the photons no longer bounced off anything. They just flew through space until they hit something. Almost all of them are still flying.
The universe expanded by a factor of 1100 since then. The wavelength of those photons is 1100 times longer. They are no longer the glow from a white hot plasma. They have expanded to become microwaves.

Before the event in our universe's history called recombination, the universe was so hot and dense that protons and electrons were mostly separated, not combined into hydrogen atoms. This meant that photons could not travel a long distance before encountering a free electron or proton and Compton scattering off of them. The universe was 'opaque' to electromagnetic radiation, as is often said.
However, around 260.000-380.000 years into the universe's evolution, the cosmic soup cooled down enough that hydrogen could form (hence the name 'recombination', of which the 're' part is a bit of a misnomer, since hydrogen had never formed before in the universe). As a result, the mean free path of photons was raised drastically, and the universe became transparent to light. The last photons to be scattered off of the free charged particles are what we now observe as the cosmic microwave background radiation. They did not have such long wavelengths at their last scattering, but due to the expansion of the universe, they got redshifted, until they had the temperature they have today (around 3K).
However, just as every photon can interact with matter it encounters, relic photons from recombination can too. So certainly there must be some microwave photons we register that are actually photons from other, much later scattering events. However, since the universe is so large and not very dense anymore, the probability of such a scattering event is very low. So most of the microwave photons we measure are due to the CMB. Moreover, since the CMB is there all the time, it is just a question of measuring the CMB for a sufficient amount of time in order to do away with statistical fluctuations due to later scattering events or other phenomena.
TL;DR: yes, we also encounter microwave photons from later stages of the universe, but they do not affect our picture of the CMB much.
